# Lookup Column from Associated Site to Hub List (No Power Shell)

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, hub-site

I would like to get information linked from associated site list to hub list, such as various project status in individual team site list, will automatically sync to hub project portfolio list.
No power shell access available.
Anyone can help?

Or, can it be done without using hub site?

Comment: Whether project status list and project portfolio list in the same site collection or not?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: hub site and site collection is different. If they are different, I am referring to hub site that contains portfolio list and various associated team site contains project status list.

Comment: Hi, is it mission impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that project portfolio list is in the hub site, project status list is in the team site associated with sub site.

If it's like the above, lookup column is not available in this situation.

Comment: Noted with thanks. Is there any workaround or alternatives?